# Как имитировать нажатую кнопку в Android Studio при верстке

Tags: android, android-studio

Как имитировать нажатую кнопку в Android Studio при верстке не запуская приложение и не нажимая кнопку? То есть я хочу видеть сразу как меняется стиль кнопки, в зависимости от того нажата она или нет, не запуская само приложение?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это сделать через стили. Добавляем цвета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="darkwhite">#ffeeeeee</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00ffffff</color>
    <color name="semitransparent">#88000000</color>
    <color name="orange">#ffff8800</color>
    <color name="light_orange">#ffe27d18</color>
    <color name="light_blue">#ff00a2e8</color>
    <color name="black">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="menuButtonColor">#ffea8e44</color>
</resources>
```

Далее создаем файл в папке drawable где будет описано что кнопка нажата:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/light_orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange"/>
</selector>
```

и дальше прикрепляем этот файл drawable к кнопке в xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="how_it_works_button_title"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_selector" />
```

Дальше смотрим в визуальный редактор в Android Studio и подгоняем то как нужно чтобы выглядела наша кнопка.

### UPDATE

Для того чтобы посмотреть на нажатую кнопку, нужно в итоге получить такой drawable файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/light_orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@color/light_orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    </selector>
```

но потом не забудьте тег `android:state_pressed="true"` убрать в одном из item чтобы кнопка имела два состояния.

Comment: Вопрос ведь не о том как сделать, а как увидеть результат в превью студии. То есть как будет выглядеть в вашем примере `light_orange` на нажатой кнопке - кнопки ведь в превью не кликаются

Comment: @woesss, да я это видел, но подумал может можно будет убрать состояние не нажатой кнопки и оставить только состояние нажатой, вообще  изначально такое нереально насколько я знаю, в редакторе нельзя нажать на кнопку, только при эмуляции работы

Comment: Оно конечно можно перенести атрибут `android:state_pressed="true"` в другой `item` селектора - но если селекторы используются вообще и задрюкаешься с каждой кнопкой их таскать, да ещё и не забыть в конце концов вернуть их на место. Только вот и не написали вы об этом в ответе...

Comment: @woesss, спасибо за то что обратили внимание на этот нюанс, обновил ответ, просто изначально нажать кнопку в визуальном редакторе сложновато, а это на мой взгляд единственный способ который доступен